# Cloning the request when taking preview of a node

Tags: nodes, 6, entities

I have a weird issue in Drupal 6 that when taking the `preview` of a node, it's cloning and make another node type with exact same details. Any idea why this happens?

[image]

I guess the below code is working when clicking the preview button :
**modules/node/node.pages.inc**

```
/**
 * Generate a node preview.
 */
function node_preview($node) {
    if (node_access('create', $node) || node_access('update', $node)) {
        // Load the user's name when needed.
        if (isset($node->name)) {
            // The use of isset() is mandatory in the context of user IDs, because
            // user ID 0 denotes the anonymous user.
            if ($user = user_load(array('name' => $node->name))) {
                $node->uid = $user->uid;
                $node->picture = $user->picture;
            } else {
                $node->uid = 0; // anonymous user
            }
        } else if ($node->uid) {
            $user = user_load(array('uid' => $node->uid));
            $node->name = $user->name;
            $node->picture = $user->picture;
        }

        $node->changed = time();

        // Extract a teaser, if it hasn't been set (e.g. by a module-provided
        // 'teaser' form item).
        if (!isset($node->teaser)) {
            $node->teaser = empty($node->body) ? '' : node_teaser($node->body, $node->format);
            // Chop off the teaser from the body if needed.
            if (!$node->teaser_include && $node->teaser == substr($node->body, 0, strlen($node->teaser))) {
                $node->body = substr($node->body, strlen($node->teaser));
            }
        }

        // Display a preview of the node.
        // Previewing alters $node so it needs to be cloned.
        if (!form_get_errors()) {
            $cloned_node = drupal_clone($node);
            $cloned_node->build_mode = NODE_BUILD_PREVIEW;
            $output = theme('node_preview', $cloned_node);
        }
        drupal_set_title(t('Preview'));

        return $output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that afer pushing Preview button you see the node in the edit form but there is a new node created taht tou can see, for example, in the content admin page?

Comment: Yes , a new node is cloned when clicking the preview button

Comment: Do you have any custom module that alters the node edit form?

Comment: yes , there is a chance .

Comment: You should post your custom code, probably the problem is there.

Comment: @tunic , am not sure which all modules modifies the node_form using node_form_alter functionality , but node_form_submit is using in diff , certfield , configfield modules etc ..

Comment: I'm talking about custom code, not contrib modules, that's a module write by you. Also, you may have a Rule that is acting on node preview.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32353/discussion-between-icecreamsandwich-and-tunic).